# New window is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to learn tkinter in python3.
For some reasons the new window is empty (File > New Test) and I do not understand why. There are no messages about mistakes.
I guess it is something with pack(), but documentation says that Toplevel does not need pack().
Could you please tell me how to make content visible in the new window.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys

class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, master)

        fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, command=self.quit)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Start Test", underline=1, command=self.start_test)

    def quit(self):
        sys.exit(0)

    def start_test(self):
        self.app = RunTestWindow(self)

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master.title("Quiz")

        self.menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self)
        self.button1['text'] = "Hello!"
        self.button1.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="white", width=400, height=400,
            bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.grid(row=3, column=0)

class RunTestWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.window = tk.Toplevel(self)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Show me my new window")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0)


root = tk.Tk()
mw = MainWindow(root)
mw.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please, tag Python too.

Comment: you have wrong parents in widgets - you have to put widgets in `self.window`. Or `Frame` has to use `self.window` as parent and use `pack()` to show frame in window.

Comment: Many thanks. It helps!

Comment: @Suvar I would rather inherit `RunTestWindow` from a `Toplevel` instead of a `Frame` at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong parents in widgets and you may have to use `pack()` to show frame in window.

You can change it in many ways but you could do it similar to how you create main window.

```
def start_test(self):
    self.subwindow = tk.Toplevel(self)
    self.app = RunTestWindow(self.subwindow)
    self.app.pack()
```

and then in class you don't need `Toplevel()`

```
class RunTestWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Show me my new window")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

BTW: to close it you will need in main window

```
self.subwindow.destroy()
```

or in `RunTestWindow()`

```
self.master.destroy()
```

for example

```
class RunTestWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Show me my new window")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Close", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

---

Full working code

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys


class MenuBar(tk.Menu):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, master)

        fileMenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, command=self.quit)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Start Test", underline=1, command=self.start_test)

    def quit(self):
        sys.exit(0)

    def start_test(self):
        self.subwindow = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.app = RunTestWindow(self.subwindow)
        self.app.pack()


class MainWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.master.title("Quiz")

        self.menubar = MenuBar(self)
        self.master.config(menu=self.menubar)

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self)
        self.button1['text'] = "Hello!"
        self.button1.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="white", width=400, height=400,
            bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.grid(row=3, column=0)


class RunTestWindow(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Show me my new window")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Close", command=self.master.destroy)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=0)


root = tk.Tk()
mw = MainWindow(root)
mw.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you for tips.
Unfortunately, it does not work for me. It only works if use self.window in widgets.
I've never used so many classes in python. It's a bit confusing.

Comment: I add full working code. And compare with your not-working version.

Comment: Works!
Thank you!